# Collator not producing block

Tags: staking, parachain-collator, block-production, session, pallet-staking

### Changes made

In previous version things were fine. In this change, I added `pallet-staking` in the collator.
Here `Staking` is `pallet_staking::{Pallet,...}`

- Configured `pallet_staking` with reference ( but is not exactly same ) as [polkadot/kusama-runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/22836e55d41eef24ed5917fd654ee82a683a7cfe/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L595)
- Configured `pallet_authorship`

```rust
impl pallet_authorship::Config for Runtime {
    type FindAuthor = pallet_session::FindAccountFromAuthorIndex<Self, Aura>;
    type UncleGenerations = UncleGenerations;
    type FilterUncle = ();
    type EventHandler = (Staking,); //TODO: use ImOnline as second field of tuple
}
```

- Configures `pallet_session`

```rust
impl pallet_session::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type ValidatorId = <Self as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;
    // we don't have stash and controller, thus we don't need the convert as well.
    type ValidatorIdOf = pallet_staking::StashOf<Self>;
    type ShouldEndSession = pallet_session::PeriodicSessions<Period, Offset>;
    type NextSessionRotation = pallet_session::PeriodicSessions<Period, Offset>;
    type SessionManager = pallet_session::historical::NoteHistoricalRoot<Self, Staking>;
    // Essentially just Aura, but lets be pedantic.
    type SessionHandler = <SessionKeys as sp_runtime::traits::OpaqueKeys>::KeyTypeIdProviders;
    type Keys = SessionKeys;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_session::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}

impl pallet_session_historical::Config for Runtime {
        type FullIdentification = pallet_staking::Exposure<AccountId, Balance>;
        type FullIdentificationOf = pallet_staking::ExposureOf<Runtime>;
}
```

- Chain spec config of staking:

```rust
staking: StakingConfig {
            invulnerables: invulnerables.clone().iter().map(|(acc, _aura)| acc).cloned().collect(),
            validator_count: invulnerables.len() as u32,
            minimum_validator_count: 2,
            slash_reward_fraction: Perbill::from_percent(10),
            ..Default::default()
        },
```

### Problem

Now when starting this collator with help of `polkadot-launch` collator is not producing even the #1 block while relaychain was producing more than 100.

### Alternatives

But running previous version of collator the same way which had not pallet-staking and then upgrading the chain with `parachainSystem.enactAuthorize` do continue to produce block.

Note: I have not yet tested the staking behaviour but any suggestion will be welcome

Comment: You found a solution to your problem?

Comment: yup i solved this. but i dont remember how